# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on nodejs chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I'm having this issue with my node js app. I've restarted my chrome, reset settings, and I know that my server is up. I'm beyond confused as to what could be going on, I already investigated and adjusted for a CORS issue (not what was wrong).

```
request.js:114 OPTIONS http://104.236.99.212:6790/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
    ClientRequest._onFinish @   request.js:114
    (anonymous function)    @   request.js:56
    EventEmitter.emit   @   events.js:74
    finishMaybe @   _stream_writable.js:485
    afterWrite  @   _stream_writable.js:367
    afterTick   @   index.js:40
    Item.run    @   browser.js:92
    drainQueue  @   browser.js:62
```

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');    
})
```

and here is my main.js (trying to print info to the console)

```
let multichain = require("multichain-node")({
    port: 6790,
    host: '104.236.99.212',
    user: "multichainrpc",
    pass: "{pw}"
});

multichain.getInfo((err, info) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(info);
    })
```

Comment: ...you're listening on port `3000` but making requests to port `6790`?

Comment: I'm requesting port 6790 on a different host: 104.236.99.212